# Como añadir errores condicionales en Formik?

Tags: reactjs, next, formik

Tengo un formulario en Formik

```
  <Formik
    initialValues={initialValues || {
      state: "",
      reservationCheckBox: false,
      privacyCheckBox: false,
    }}
    validateOnChange={false}
    validationSchema={
      yup.object().shape({
        firstName: yup.string().required("First Name is required"),
        lastName: yup.string().required("Last Name is required"),
        email: yup.string().required("Email Address is required").email("Invalid Email Address"),
        confirmEmail: yup.string().oneOf([yup.ref("email")], "Confirm Email must match"),
        phoneNumber: yup.string().required("Phone Number is required").length(USA_PHONE.length, "Phone Number is invalid"),
        streetAddress: yup.string().required("Street Address is required"),
        postalCode: yup.string().required("Postal Code is required").min(5, "Postal Code is invalid").max(ZIP_CODE.length, "Postal Code is invalid"),
        postalCodeCAN: yup.string().required("Postal Code is required CAN").min(7, "Postal Code is invalid CAN min").max(CANADA_ZIP_CODE.length, "Postal Code is invalid CAN max"),
        city: yup.string().required("City is required"),
        state: yup.string().required("State is required").oneOf(Object.keys(STATE_NAMES), "Invalid State"),
        reservationCheckBox: yup.bool().oneOf([true], "You need to accept the terms"),
        privacyCheckBox: yup.bool().oneOf([true], "You need to accept the terms"),
      })
    }
    onSubmit={onSubmit}
  >
```

Y como veran hay dos campos para el postal code. Uno para Canada y otro general.

Luego en mi componente, renderizo un campo u otro dependiendo de un valor de mi formulario

```
 {values?.state === "CAN" ? (
            <TextField
              FormHelperTextProps={{
                className: "helper-text",
              }}
              className="booking-input postal-code"
              defaultValue={values?.postalCode}
              error={Boolean(errors?.postalCodeCAN)}
              helperText={errors?.postalCodeCAN}
              label="Postal Code"
              name="postalCodeCAN"
              onChange={e => {
                e.target.value = formatWithMask({
                  text: e.target.value,
                  mask: CANADA_ZIP_CODE,
                }).masked;

                handleChange(e);
              }}
            />
          ) :
              (
                <TextField
                  FormHelperTextProps={{
                    className: "helper-text",
                  }}
                  className="booking-input postal-code"
                  defaultValue={values?.postalCode}
                  error={Boolean(errors?.postalCode)}
                  helperText={errors?.postalCode}
                  label="Postal Code"
                  name="postalCode"
                  onChange={e => {
                    if (e.target.value.length <= 6) {
                      e.target.value = e.target.value.replace("-", "");
                    }
                    if (e.target.value.length > 5) {
                      e.target.value = formatWithMask({
                        text: e.target.value,
                        mask: ZIP_CODE,
                      }).masked;
                    }

                    handleChange(e);
                  }}
                />
              )}
```

Todo parece funcionar bien, las condiciones, errores, masks, todo funciona excepto una cosa: El formulario siempre arroja un error.

Sospecho que es porque cuando existe `postalCodeCAN`, `postalCode` no existe y visceversa. Hay alguna forma de agregar estos dos errores de manera condicional al objeto `validationSchema`?

Answer (score 0):

no sabia que podia hacer uso de `when` para condicionar estos errores. Lo solucioné haciendo

```
 postalCode: yup.string().when("state", {
      is: val => val !== "CAN",
      then: yup.string().required("Postal Code is required").min(5, "Postal Code is invalid").max(ZIP_CODE.length, "Postal Code is invalid"),
      otherwise: yup.string().notRequired(),
    }),

    postalCodeCAN: yup.string().when("state", {
      is: "CAN",
      then: yup.string().required("Postal Code is required CAN").min(7, "Postal Code is invalid CAN min").max(CANADA_ZIP_CODE.length, "Postal Code is invalid CAN max"),
      otherwise: yup.string().notRequired(),
    }),
```